# If G/N is abelian, then prove that C $\subset$ N, where C is commutator subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Beforehand, this is not a homework question. I am solving every single problems in Herstein's Topic in Algebra, and ran into this problem. This is the solution I found:

http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/zls002/Math370Fa14/HW/370sols7.pdf

The book does not describe whether N is a normal subgroup of G, but the solution exploits the fact that N, by definition, is normal in G. (Of course, the word abelian only makes sense in the context of group. Thus, I am forced to make an assumption that G/N is a group in its own right). Thus, can I solve the problem without making an assumption that N is normal in G?

$NaNb = NbNa$, but does not necessarily mean $NaNb \neq Nab \\ a,b \in G$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But for G/N to be a group N has to be normal

Comment: You missed the fact that *Given a subgroup $N$ of $G$, $G/N$ is a group iff $N$ is normal in $G$.*